# Computing Gaussian curvature from a unit normal vector of a given surface

Tags: differential-geometry

For a implicit surface, $F(x,y,z)=0$. My main goal is obtaining
\begin{align}
  K  =  - \frac{\begin{vmatrix}
     H(F) & \nabla F^T \\
     \nabla F & 0
  \end{vmatrix}}{|\nabla F|^4}
  = - \frac{\begin{vmatrix}
    F_{xx} & F_{xy} & F_{xz} & F_x \\
    F_{xy} & F_{yy} & F_{yz} & F_y \\
    F_{xz} & F_{yz} & F_{zz} & F_z \\
    F_x & F_y & F_z & 0
  \end{vmatrix}}{|\nabla F|^4}
\end{align}
what I know is its unit normal vector is $ N = \frac{\nabla F}{|\nabla F|}$. Is there any systematic way of computing Gaussian curvature out of normal vector and its derivatives?

Comment: This article might be useful: [Goldman, R. (2005). "Curvature formulas for implicit curves and surfaces". Computer Aided Geometric Design. 22 (7): 632.](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.413.3008)